# Angular project did not run

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to run my angular project using 'ng serve' command.

but project did not run more errors in my terminal. please check attached screen and give me the solution.

thanks [image]

Comment: npm install node-sass

Answer (score 0):

Try installing node-sass

```
sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try installing below package

```
npm install -g mirror-config-china --registry=http://registry.npm.taobao.org
```

OR try below one if the above doesn't work.

```
npm install node-sass
```